# How can I debug on Azure Devops VSO

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have made a task for Azure Devops Server pipeline.

On the local Azure Dev-Ops server, I can upload extensions from the local machine wrapped in VSIX file and examine the agent on the machine itself. The agent has the deployed DLL's from the extension and I always change specific DLL that has Logger inside and it prints to console on the pipeline itself.

How can I check if my task is compatible with the cloud version?
And off course if it is, how can I debug it?

The only possible way I found to insert my task in VSO is through the Microsoft DevOps marketplace, but I cannot upload the whole extension once per each change in code.

Also, didn't find a way to upload personal tasks to the marketplace. The private version is not helping because I can see it from within the server just like my clients.

Any advice or debug experience on that platform is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow this [devblogs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/streamlining-azure-devops-extension-development/), it described how you can work and debug extension directly inside your IDE without publishing it to the marketplace.

Since this blog is very detailed, just mention the key steps.

Based on debugging purposes, you need create a special manifest, for sample I specify it as `vss-extension-debug.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "id": "dev-extension",
  "name": "Dev-Extension",
  "baseUri": "https://localhost:44362",
  ...
}
```

You can customized the `id` and `name` by yourself. The most **important and magic** is `baseUri`, this will tell the VSTS server to load the extension from localhost where we can run and debug it in **IISExpress** from Visual Studio.

**Note**: Since our server need extension served from a secure source, please ensure enable **SSL** mode to run IISExpress

[image]

Comment: I found out I can upload the VSIX to DevOps marketplace and make it private, then share it to specific dev organization where I work on it and debug with console prints just like in the old times.
Your solution is much better, allows live inspection and debugging, thank you!